# Running Pytorch on an Azure VM (A100 GPU) is only using 4% of CPU and GPU

Tags: azure, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to train a deep reinforcement learning model using an `Azure NC24ads_A100_v4` VM which has 24 vcpus and a 80gb A100 GPU.

`Pytorch` version is 2.0.1 with `Cuda` version 12,
Azure VM image is `Ubuntu-HPC 20.04` which is supposedly meant to be for this type of VM.

My code runs fine, both on CPU and GPU, as at the beginning I check if `cuda` is available by

```
device = torch.device(
    'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
```

And I move my model, state, reward batch to the device which is being used as follows:

```
cur_state = cur_state.to(device)
disc_returns = disc_returns.to(device)
model.to(device)
```

Now the issue is, it runs really slow compared to what is should be doing on such a VM. My model is relatively small.

```
model = torch.nn.Sequential(
    torch.nn.Linear(152, 200),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(200, 200),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(200, 25),
    torch.nn.ReLU(),
    torch.nn.Linear(25, 4),
    torch.nn.LogSoftmax(dim=0)
)
```

When I am using a `Pytorch` version with CPU only, I can see that all CPUs are being used and after a very short amount of time it is already using around 80% of the CPU.

When I use `Pytorch` with `Cuda`, both CPU and GPU is only running on around 4%.

This VM has 24 CPUs, 100 % 24 is 4.1...

[image]

[image]

This is a very significant decrease in speed and I need to fix this to make use of all available resources. It should run around 24 times faster. Do I need to distribute the load somehow? I mean if I would have more than one GPU available, I would understand it, but it does not make any sense to me.

PS: I do check if `Cuda` is available and the device which will be used is printed out at the beginning.

**-- UPDATE --**

I have just timed both a sample iteration using CPU and GPU, and I seem to get roughly the same result which was 50 seconds. I also time the same iteration on my local desktop which is an `Intel I3` CPU and it it only took 100 seconds which is just half the speed. Clearly the VM should be a lot faster.

I would also like to add, at the point where I was timing the performance, there were no external dependecies, such as reading from a DB or from a disk. All data was already loaded into memory and I was only using batches of that data to train my model.

Comment: Provide your training code.

Comment: also check whether your device specs are correctly parsed to pytorch, for that examine: `gpu = torch.cuda.get_device_properties(torch.cuda.current_device())`

Comment: I resolved it by using `torch.multiprocessing` with shared memory. I still do not understand why you have to manually setup things to be using all CPU cores..